# Actionscript Chat Room Help

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, chatroom

I am trying to create a chatroom using Flash and Action script. I want it to look like and have the same functionality as the chatrooms at cam4.com (WARNING: NOT SAFE FOR WORK. DON'T CLICK THE LINKIF YOU ARE AT WORK. SERIOUSLY, DON'T CLICK IT.)

Any idea how they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they are using Flash - and probably Actionscript 3..

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh - technically my answer does answer the OP question of 'Any idea how they do it?'

Comment: Yeah. A bit snarky, but then again, the question sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript 3 + A flash server supporting shared objects like Red5 or Flash Media Server.